# How to add a null character to an end of a string in Assembly Language

Tags: string, assembly, nasm

I am very new to assembly language, and I just worked on a project where I reversed a string from a source. I am trying to figure out how to add a null character to the end of my target string.

I was trying to use ADD, but since this is not arithmetic, I should probably not be using that:

```
add target[edi], 0x00               ; adds a null character to the end of the target string
```

But I just have not learned enough to know how to concatenate a null value to the end of a string. Any help is greatly appreciated!

My code is:

```
.386
.model flat, stdcall
.stack 4096
ExitProcess proto, dwExitCode:dword

.data
source BYTE "This is the string that will be reversed", 0
target BYTE SIZEOF source DUP('#')

.code
    main proc
    mov esi, OFFSET target - 2          ; index register for source
    mov edi, 0                          ; index register for target
    mov ecx, SIZEOF source              ; loop counter
LOOPM :
    mov al, [esi]                       ; gets character from source using indirect addressing. If OFFSET were not used on line 16, this would just be source[esi], not [esi]
    mov target[edi], al                 ; stores the character in target
    inc edi                             ; moves to the next index for target
    dec esi                             ; moves to the next character in the source
    loop LOOPM
    ;   Loop is over now.
    add target[edi], 0x00                 ; adds a null character to the end of the target string
invoke ExitProcess, 0
main endp
end main
```

Comment: Adding 0 to an integer is a no-op.  You want `mov` to store a `0` terminator, if there's already space reserved for you to do so.  It will overwrite whatever was in memory before.  Strings in static storage like that are just like C `static char target[sizeof(source)] = { '#', '#', ... };`.  BTW, it would be a easier to have your copy loop just include the terminating `0` byte as part of what it copies.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thank you so much for responding! This is really stressing me out haha! That makes sense. I knew adding wasn't right but I couldn't quite figure out what to do. I've now made it be mov target[edi], 0, but my memory still isn't saying the zero. It must be something to do with the allocation of memory then, right?

Comment: After `mov target[edi], 0` executes, there will definitely be a zero byte in memory at that position.  In your code, after the loop `edi` should hold `sizeof source`, so `target[edi]` should be one past the end of the array...  And in the loop, the last iteration reads 1 byte before the start of `source`.  Use the debugger to single-step and look at register values, especially AL on the first and last iterations, and EDI after the loop.  And adjust your loop bounds accordingly.  You might want `target BYTE SIZEOF source-1 DUP('#'), 0` if that's valid syntax since `source` includes its `,0`